# Check if AlarmManager exists always returning false

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I want to show a daily notification with helping of `AlarmManager`.

It was working properly until I tried to make it persistent after reboot

I create the Alarm as follows:

```
if (switch_notif.isChecked()){ //in my activity's code
    NotificationReceiver.scheduleAlarms(getApplicationContext()); //allow the notification

} else {
    NotificationReceiver.stopNotif(getApplicationContext()); //disable them
}
```

Here is my broadcast receiver:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Log.d("NotificationReceiver", "onReceive");
        this.sendNotif(context);

        //trying to see if there is already an alarm in place (for reboot)
        boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100,
                new Intent(),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
        Log.d("NotificationReceiver", alarmUp? "true":"false" ); //always return false

        if (alarmUp)
        {
            //Log.d("NotificationReceiver", "Alarm is already active");
        }
        else { //if no alarm, schedule one
            //Log.d("NotificationReceiver", "Alarm is not active");
            this.scheduleAlarms(context); 

        }
    }

    public static void scheduleAlarms(Context context) {

        //Log.d("NotificationReceiver", "scheduleAlarms");
        Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 31);
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
        /*if (now.after(alarmStartTime)) { // not needed when using 1min repeat for testing
            Log.d("Alarm","Added a day");
            alarmStartTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }*/

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(),60000 ,pendingIntent); // set to 1minute for testing purpose

    }

    public static void sendNotif(Context context){ //fire the notification

        //Log.d("NotificationReceiver", "sendNotif");
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Notification.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context, 100, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif)
                .setContentTitle("Rappel MyCardioPad")
                .setContentText("Vous avez une séance d'éffort aujourd'hui")
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());

    }

    public static void stopNotif(Context context){ //Allow to turn off the alarm/notification

        //Log.d("NotificationReceiver", "stopNotif");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        pendingIntent.cancel();
    }
}
```

edit:
This is the log from when I turn off and turn on the alarm:

```
07-20 14:22:58.637 mycardiopad D/NotificationReceiver: scheduleAlarms
07-20 14:22:59.856 mycardiopad D/NotificationReceiver: onReceive
07-20 14:22:59.856 mycardiopad D/NotificationReceiver: sendNotif
07-20 14:22:59.863 mycardiopad D/NotificationReceiver: false
07-20 14:22:59.863 mycardiopad D/NotificationReceiver: Alarm is not active
07-20 14:22:59.863 mycardiopad D/NotificationReceiver: scheduleAlarms
07-20 14:22:59.908 mycardiopad D/NotificationReceiver: onReceive
07-20 14:22:59.908 mycardiopad D/NotificationReceiver: sendNotif
07-20 14:22:59.912 mycardiopad D/NotificationReceiver: false
07-20 14:22:59.912 mycardiopad D/NotificationReceiver: Alarm is not active
07-20 14:22:59.912 mycardiopad D/NotificationReceiver: scheduleAlarms
07-20 14:23:00.509 mycardiopad D/NotificationReceiver: onReceive
07-20 14:23:00.509 mycardiopad D/NotificationReceiver: sendNotif
07-20 14:23:00.520 mycardiopad D/NotificationReceiver: false
07-20 14:23:00.520 mycardiopad D/NotificationReceiver: Alarm is not active
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe, `alarmUp` is always false because your are using a different `Intent` to compare them

Checking if they exist:

```
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

Creating the alarm:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Notification.class);
intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

As you can see, `Intent` use in both statment are different.
Try to check as below:

```
Intent tempIntent = new Intent(context, Notification.class);
tempIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100, tempIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

**By the way**

All alarms are destroyed during a reboot... So, you should register your `BroadcastReceiver` to receive `BOOT_COMPLETED` events. This way, when you receive `BOOT_COMPLETED` event, you know that your device was rebooted and no alarm is active... Then, you crete them again.

Comment: Thank you that was it !  
I had correctly registered the BroadcastReceiver, thanks, just messed up the checking.  
I also writted "Notification.class" instead of "NotificationReceiver.class" in sendNotif but it was still wroking like this (or was this the change you suggested ? i change something but not this and it's now working)
I'm stil  not sure how it work, i though it was with the id (100 here)

Comment: Thank you very much! i had similar issue, turned out my intents weren't matching, even though requestCode was the same.